# Files with tabs are length 8 even with set tabstop=4 in vimrc

Tags: indentation, tab-characters

I have most of the usual tab commands in `~/.vimrc`:

`set tabstop=4` `set softtabstop=4` `set shiftwidth=4` `set expandtab`

`set breakindent` `set autoindent` `set smartindent`.

There are no problems when I open a file that uses spaces over tabs; all tabs produce 4 spaces. But when I open a file someone else has written using tabs, the tabs produce a space of length 8 and stretches out the lines. I can remove this by typing `:set tabstop=4` but why must I do this when that command is already loaded in `~/.vimrc`? How can I make it automatically alter the tabs to length 4 upon opening the file?

Comment: Which filetype are you editing? Some filetypes reset `tabstop`. You can also use `:verbose set tabstop` to check where it was last set.

Comment: I'm editing a python file.

Comment: Yup, Python is one of the filetypes that resets it. See the linked question on how to fix it.

Comment: Could you tell me what other common file types also resets `tabstop` or where I can look this up? Does this apply to e.g. `C`, `C++`, or `Java` files?

Comment: There isn't a full list, but something like `ag setlocal /usr/share/vim/vim80/{ftplugin,indent,syntax}` comes reasonably close (use `grep -r` if you don't have `ag` installed).